# How can I use ndb outside of appengine?

Tags: python, database, google-cloud-datastore, flask-sqlalchemy, app-engine-ndb

I really like GAE's object-relational database tools, db and ndb.  I am currently preparing to develop a server which needs to be hosted from a local machine outside of Google's cloud environment.  Namely, I am planning to use a python flask server.

I've used other tools like SQLAlchemy to interact with a database, but I really prefer using ndb.  Some searches about using ndb outside of GAE indicated google cloud support, but this is also not an option.

Is it even possible to use ndb outside of the Appengine environment?  Are there any examples of it being done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this can work using the [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi). Note that the process for setting up Remote API is a little complicated and using it has [some limitations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api#limitations).

[This article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api) walks through the steps about how to set it up for db, however the process is the same for ndb.

Comment: Just a note that the Datastore team is actively working to allow you to use ndb through the Cloud Datastore API, however we do not yet have a time period for when that will be ready.